# Can I add and edit a custom entity from the same URL?

Tags: 8, entities

I am creating a custom entity called user_profile. Each logged in user will have a user profile. I want to be able to add and edit the user_profile entity from the same URL.

The example module provided at

[Creating a Content Entity Type in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/creating-a-content-entity-type-in-drupal-8)

shows adding and editing with the same form but from different URLs.

I want to be able to create the profile when the profile does not exist and edit the profile when the profile does exist from the same URL like /user/3/my-profile

Comment: Maybe the profile module (https://www.drupal.org/project/profile) will suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks @quex. Wanted to handle it with custom entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a controller in its simplest form.

In my_module.routing.yml :

```
my_module.profile_controller_profile:
  path: '/user/{user}/my-profile'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\ProfileController::profile'
    _title: 'Profile'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'edit profile'
    user: \d+
```

In ProfileController.php :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormBuilderInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\my_module\Entity\Profile;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Class ProfileController.
 */
class ProfileController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  /**
   * Constructs a new ProfileController object.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormBuilderInterface $entity_form_builder
   */
  public function __construct(
    EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager,
    EntityFormBuilderInterface $entity_form_builder
  ) {
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
    $this->entityFormBuilder = $entity_form_builder;
  }


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('entity_type.manager'),
      $container->get('entity.form_builder')
    );
  }

  /**
   * @param \Drupal\user\Entity\User $user
   *
   * @return array
   * @throws \Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\InvalidPluginDefinitionException
   * @throws \Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException
   */
  public function profile(User $user) {
    $profiles = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('profile')->loadByProperties(
      ['user_id' => $user->id()]
    );
    if ($profiles) {
      $profile = array_pop($profiles);
      $action = 'edit';
    } else {
      $profile = Profile::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id(),
      ]);
      $action = 'add';
    }
    return $this->entityFormBuilder->getForm($profile, $action);
  }

}
```

You can choose to redirect after submitting the form, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That's simple. In your form's build() function check for an existing entity for that user. If there is one, prefill the fields (set #default_value). Maybe add the existing entity-id as hidden field (if any).

In your form's submit() check again for an existing entity (for security reasons) or use the hidden entity-id. Then decide in your code if you create an new entity or modify the existing one.

Comment: That would work for a custom form. This is the entity form for a custom entity. The answer by @Condutiarii works